# How should the files looklike for Macosx javapackager?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I have these files:

```
MyApp-post-image.sh  (empty right now?)
MyApp-icns (OK)
MyApp-background.png (OK)
MyApp-volume.incs (OK)
MyApp-dmg-setup.scpt (empty?)
list.plist (Empty?)
```

Any ideas what to include in these empty files?

Comment: What issue are you facing when you are using javapackager?

Comment: See updated question! I dont get any .dmg icon image or have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and got the packaging with images working on both Windows and Mac.

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/

For the mac I have only added the two icns files. Be carefull to put them in the right place. (See tutorial) I'd also be carefull with empty files because if a needed file is missing the packager will use some default but I don't know what will happen if you provide an empty file.

Comment: Thanks, but not helping in this case, i running from terminal the jvapackager and have all files within the package/macosx/ and everything works fine but NO icon for the .dmg file itself :(

Comment: My question still the same, what to put into the file .plist / .sh and .scpt in this case?

Comment: So why do you insist on providing these files. I don't know the command line version of the packager but I don't think it is so much different from the Ant task. I haven't provided any of the files you mentioned and everything works as expected. Why make things more complicated as they are if you do not have a specific reason to provide these files.

Comment: Well i have reason for contribution of these files thats why i want to be able to change the icon on the .dmg file as well :)

Comment: So same question still, what to write in the empty files anyone?